# Carmen Rails- Devise - Rails 4: issue with country_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new and I have a basic question

When I create a new user with devise using carmen-rails with Rails 4, country_code and states_code don't pass

Both country_code and state_code are permitted

Here are my codes:

in Devise registration:

```
= f.label :country_code 
= f.country_select :country_code, {priority: %w(US CA), prompt: "Please select your country"}, :style => "width:170px;float:left;font-size:14px;", :type => 'text'
= f.label :state_code
= render partial: '/users/subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country_code}
```

in users/ subregionselect:

```
<% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %> <% unless parent_region.nil? %>
<% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %> 
<% end %>

<% if country.nil? %>
Please select a country above
<% elsif country.subregions? %>
<%= f.subregion_select(:user, :state_code, parent_region) %>
<% else %>
<%= text_field(:user, :state_code) %>
<% end %>
```

in users.js.coffee

```
$('select#user_country_code').change (event) ->
select_wrapper = $('#user_state_code_wrapper')

$('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true)

country_code = $(this).val()

url = "/users/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"
select_wrapper.load(url)
```

in routes.rb

```
get '/users/subregion_options' => 'users#subregion_options'
```

in users controllers:

```
def subregion_options
render partial: 'subregion_select'
end
```

On my console, all the data are saved except for country_code: nil (even though I put United States) and the states_code is not generated when I select a country.

Is that because I should need to use Formstatic?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: your question is not clear, Did you able to generate country select and state select view and problem with getting parameter to save only ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with Devise params sanitation.

```
#application_controller

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| 
         u.permit(:email, 
                  :password, 
                  :password_confirmation, 
                  :first_name, 
                  :last_name, 
                  :street1, 
                  :street2, 
                  :city,
                  :state, 
                  :zipcode, 
                  :country_code) 
 }
```

Give that a try!

Cheers